# SES callback for completed domain identity verification

Tags: python, boto, amazon-ses

I'm validating domain identities through the `boto` python client.  Once the domain has been verified, I would like to receive a callback to one of my REST endpoints.

Is this possible?  I wanted to avoid polling but will if its the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no provisions for this.  The only event-like things that SES spontaneously emits are delivery, bounce, and complaint [notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications-via-sns.html).